# Loading animation is not working across browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a basic loading animation. It is supposed to run when a user clicks on an upload button.

Now it works perfectly in Chrome and UC Browser. But it isn't working in Safari and Opera Mini. I must support these browsers too.

First time developing such stuff, hence confused about where am I going wrong. Is it my CSS which isn't working is it that my jQuery isn't executing?

My HTML code:

```
  {{ form.photo1 }}
  <div class="loader">
      <div class="spinner"></div>
  aik min</div>
  <input type="submit" class="UploadBtn btn bl cl bco mbs mts" style="border-color:#f57c00;" value="Upload">
```

My CSS code:

```
.loader {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: serif;
    color: #00C853;
    display: none;
}
.spinner {
    border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 5px solid #FFA000;
    border-right: 5px solid #00C853;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #FF9933;
    border-left: 5px solid #00C853;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    display: none;

}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* added vendor specific css (IE) */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* added vendor specific css (Safari, Opera , Chrome) */
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* added vendor specific css (IE) */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* added vendor specific css (Safari, Opera , Chrome) */
  }
}

@-o-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* added vendor specific css (IE) */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* added vendor specific css (Safari, Opera , Chrome) */
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* added vendor specific css (IE) */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* added vendor specific css (Safari, Opera , Chrome) */
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* added vendor specific css (IE) */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* added vendor specific css (Safari, Opera , Chrome) */
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* added vendor specific css (IE) */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* added vendor specific css (Safari, Opera , Chrome) */
  }
    }
```

My jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".UploadBtn", function(event) {
        $(".p").each(function(file) {
            if  ($(this).val()) {
                $(".loader").show();
                $(".spinner").show();
                $("#overlay").show();
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Please note that 'p' class is for `{{ form.photo1 }}` which is written in Django.

Comment: `it isn't working` - can you describe this in more detail? debugging 101 - **browser developer tools** - errors/warnings/odd messages in the console can show you the way - any browser that doesn't have such tools is not worth writing for

Comment: I think there are no error messages generated, since it seems to be a support problem for the CSS properties. Sure, those browsers he noted are old and for an usual webpage not worth debugging for, but since he explicitly stated, that he had to support those browsers...

Comment: There are no error messages. The page renders completely but the loading animation never runs. It is suppose to run when a user selects a file and clicks on the upload button but instead while the file is getting uploaded the animation doesn't run.

Comment: Just an additional note: Since `@-webkit-keyframes` only targets WebKit browsers you don't need `-ms` prefixed properties in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=animation%20%7C%20transform) `animation` and `transform` is not supported in Opera mini and very old versions of Safari. Therefore your only chance is to fallback to JS animations in those browsers or better use an animated gif as a loading animation.

Comment: I am using Safari Version 10.1.1 (12603.2.4) and I may sound like a noob but will jQuery animations work in those browsers?

Comment: In Safari 10.1 it should work without problems.
jQuery's `animate` function should work, but your next problem is that there seems to be no way to rotate your element (in Opera mini). It would be better to fallback to a loading animation in form of a gif.

Comment: So in short I should get rid of my CSS loader and instead just add a GIF which should run using jQuery.

Comment: Probably the easiest way would be to simply display a GIF in an image element. If you plan to drop support for Opera Mini soon, you could also use your code and display the image only when you detect that the animation isn't working.

Comment: Is there a way to run a CSS based animation in a particular browser and a GIF in another using jQuery? The clients requirement is that an animation has to run on Opera Mini as majority of the users are using that browser.

Comment: You could use https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Detecting_CSS_animation_support for detecting support. However in that case I would just use an image.

Comment: by image do you mean a GIF or a static image? Isn't GIF compatible with Opera Mini?

Comment: You are right, I didn't think there are any browsers in use which don't support GIF. Then an alternative would be to use an image sprite (http://www.webmaster-source.com/2012/06/04/animating-a-css-sprite-with-javascript/) or just don't display the loading animation.

Comment: Could you please update your answer to recommend the code via which i can run a GIF instead of the CSS loading animation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150413/discussion-between-stephan-and-shahz).

Comment: Kindly reply in chat :)